# не ставится current time stamp из запроса php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Простая форма с простым запросом. Вопрос- что нужно поставить в php запрос чтобы на mysql сервере проставлялся `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` автоматически?! Пробовал `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `NOW()`, `time()`. Но все манипуляции приводят к `0000-00-00 00:00:00` в поле `date`. 
В phpMyAdmin все отрабатывает, что не так с запросом пока не понимаю.

```
<form action="zakaz.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="comment" type="text" />
            <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?echo 'west';?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Подать заявку"/>
            </form>     
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['user_id'])){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    // создание строки запроса
    $query1 ="INSERT INTO zayavka VALUES(NULL, '0', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', '0', '$user_id' ,'$comment')";
    // выполняем запрос
    $result = mysql_query($query1) or die("Ошибка " . mysql_error($connect)); 
    if($result)
    {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.setTimeout(function() {location.href='zakaz.php';}, 10);</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Структура таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'zayavka' (
id int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tip int(15) NOT NULL,
date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
status int(5) NOT NULL,
user int(15) NOT NULL,
comment varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=30;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tableName` SET `tip` = "0", `status` = "0", `user` = '{$user_id}', `comment` = '{$comment}'";
```

Comment: Не помогло. Хотя я понял, что нужно использовать SET, но результат остался прежним.

Comment: Идея не в использовании SET, а в том, чтобы ничего не передавать в поле "date". В этом случае должно установиться значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Идею я сразу понял=) Просто вообще забыл напрочь о SET...=) Да и я был не прав- этот запрос отработал нормально, у меня форма ссылалась не на тот скрипт где я SET не использовал. Так что все работает=) Спасибо!
Бывает такое что очевидные вещи не приходят в голову... Спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо поля timestamp можете время с функции date передавать:

> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `zayavka` (`date`) VALUES('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."');
```

Хоть `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` сам поставится если поле не передать, но, может быть актуально, если используются разные временные зоны в php и mysql. Тут уже смотря на какое время ориентируетесь.